# How do I build a Docker image for an ARM device?

Tags: docker, go, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm noticing `exec user process caused "exec format error"` when trying to run a Docker image on a Raspberry Pi 4.

First I'm bewildered that a Docker image is pulled that won't run on the platform to begin with. Nonetheless I am keen to make it work, but I don't know how.

Here's the project: https://github.com/kaihendry/sla How can I build ARM compatible images?

Comment: Did you build this image on your pi ?

Answer (score 3):

The `FROM golang` line will pull the appropriate architecture; they have arm v6 (older pi / pi 0 running raspbian) + arm v7 (newer pi running raspbian) and arm64 (newer pi running ubuntu) as part of a multi-arch docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/golang?tab=tags

Your problem with exec format error (i.e. it is the wrong binary format) appears to just be the line https://github.com/kaihendry/sla/blob/a22d983340f3df794696e5c8e31cf3b89f7edd89/Dockerfile#L14 where your architecture is wrong for a pi; it should be GOARCH=arm (32 bit, non-ubuntu) or GOARCH=arm64 (ubuntu), additionally for 32 bit ARM (v6 and v7) you would also need to specify GOARM=6 or GOARM=7 per https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoArm

I have tested your code with a swap to to GOARCH=arm64 (and no GOARM required) and had it build and run on my pi3b+ running ubuntu.

Noting for future reference I suspect my answer may change if/when raspbian switches to 64 bit.

Comment: I think I have something working here https://github.com/kaihendry/sla/commit/8c5baca56e5674a28741d354b2f7ed3f6880bcfc but the manifest part doesn't appear to work properly when testing on rpi4 with `docker run -it hendry/sla:latest`

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is that if the `go build` is done as part of Dockerfile in a build using [buildx](https://github.com/docker/buildx), targeting a different architecture(or multiple architectures), `GOARCH` doesn't need to be specified. Just need to specify which platforms/architectures to target as part of the `buildx` command. The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/devatherock/simple-slack/blob/2192cfeac3d48441bcf88ac1ae5ee3f54b29fcc5/build/Dockerfile) in one of my projects looks like the below:

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine3.19 AS build

COPY . /home/workspace
WORKDIR /home/workspace

RUN go build -o bin/simpleslack ./...


FROM alpine:3.19.1

COPY --from=build /home/workspace/bin/simpleslack /bin/simpleslack

CMD ["/bin/simpleslack"]
```

Note that the go build command, `RUN go build -o bin/simpleslack ./...`, doesn't specify a `GOARCH`. Then the [buildx command(s)](https://github.com/devatherock/simple-slack/blob/2192cfeac3d48441bcf88ac1ae5ee3f54b29fcc5/.circleci/config.yml#L118-L126), that build a multi-arch image targeting `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64` from the above dockerfile, look something like below:

```
  docker buildx create --name custombuilder \
    --driver docker-container --use --bootstrap
  docker buildx build \
      --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
      --push -t devatherock/simple-slack:latest \
      -f build/Dockerfile .
```

The created [multi-arch image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/devatherock/simple-slack/general) runs fine in x86(linux/amd64) as well as arm64 machines.